# SerialPort Datareceive in vb.net - how can I parse the data received

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, serialization, serial-port

I have a PC that sends Serial data to a sign.  What I'd like to do is remove the  sign, and display it on my own using a .Net program, and another PC.  I have a .Net program that reads the data from a com port (serial cable from PC to PC)-  The reading is working just fine, however i'm not sure how to properly parse the data I want, and display it in a Label.

Here is how it currently works.

- The computer sends transaction information (price) to the com port.  30 seconds later, it sends the termination of the string - to indicate we no longer want to display the information anymore.
- I'm able to See this, including the price, with the start of the message and end of the message characters.  Image of the data i'm receiving in my current .net is below.  You'll notice it sends the 01 Then the price, in this case 2000 ($20.00).  Then after 30 seconds, it displays the remaining characters.

[image]

Here is my Current Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1
    Dim myport As Array
    Delegate Sub settextcallback(ByVal [text] As String)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'This is the connect button
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM3" 'Connect on COM3
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = "1200" 'Set BaudRate to 1200
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Button1.Enabled = False


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
'this is the disconnect button
        SerialPort1.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting)

    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
'now we display the information
        If Me.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then

            Dim x As New settextcallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})


        Else
            Me.RichTextBox1.Text &= [text]

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I parse out the leading 01, and just display, in this case, $20.00 in a label - let's call it "label1", until I receive the trailing '01'.  Once I receive the trailing '01', I want to Clear the label.

I've attempted to clear, then transfer the text box in the thread however, since the data comes in one at a time - that doesn't give me the result i'm looking for.

Comment: The output is always something like $XXXXX$XX ?

Comment: @noidea Yes - the output will be exactly the same except for the inner 4 characters.  I do have the ability to add a decimal point too if that makes parsing easier. so an example:  $012000$01   $011500$01  Or, I can do: $0120.00$01  You get the idea - it's always leading $01 then a trailing $01 after 30 seconds to indicate we no longer should be displaying it.

Comment: So u just want to format the output value from the richtextbox? and place it in a label?

Comment: More or less.  I want only the inner 4 characters (the price).  And display it in a label, until I receive the trailing "01"  When I receive the trailing "01" I want to Clear the label to display nothing, until I receive the next Price, which I'll display again until i receive the trailing "01"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is very robust but you can figure it out on your own.

Put this in a timer and it works fine.

```
Private Sub TimerPrice_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerPrice.Tick

Dim output As Array = TextBox1.Text.Split("#")

    If output.Length = 2 Then
        Label1.Text = output(1)
    Else
        Label1.Text = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This got me where I needed to be.